# How to find $f(x)$

Tags: functions

$$f(x)+3f\left({1\over{x}}\right)=x$$

Okay so I tried saying that $f(x)=y$ and $f({1\over{x}})={1\over{y}}$

Solving this for $y$ I got

$y_{1/2}={{x\pm\sqrt{x^2-12}}\over2}$

But I'm not sure if this is even correct to do and if it is should I use $+$ or $-$?

Any help?

Edit:
Thanks to user lulu for pointing out my mistake and driving me to the correct path.

Just changing up the equation I got the second one
$$f({1\over{x}})+3f(x)={1\over{x}}$$

Solving both as a system of equations I got that
$$f(x)={3-x^2\over{8x}}$$

Comment: Why would you expect that  $f\left( \frac 1x\right)=\frac 1{f(x)}$?

Comment: Had no other ideas really, so I assumed that in my imagination apparently

Comment: Hint:  letting $x\mapsto \frac 1x$ in the original equation, we get $f\left( \frac 1x\right)+3f(x)=\frac 1x$  Now combine that with the original equation.

Comment: @lulu to do this, you have to suppose $f$ continuous

Comment: @DiegoMath  No, I don't.  I'm just relabeling the argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have the system$$f(x)+3f\left(\dfrac 1x\right)=x\\f\left(\dfrac 1x\right)+3f(x)=\dfrac 1x$$ from which $$f(x)=\dfrac{3}{8x}-\frac x8$$

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, you can't assume that if $f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$; however, despite that assumption, your answer was right.

EDIT: I read your edit...

The key is to realize that if $f(x)+3f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=x$ then by means of rearranging, $f(x)=x-3f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ which implies that, by substitution, $f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac{1}{x}-3f(x)$. Finally, substitute $f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ back into $f(x)$ to get
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=x-3\left(\frac{1}{x}-3f(x)\right)\\
&=x-\frac{3}{x}+9f(x)\\
f(x)&=\boxed{-\frac{x^2-3}{8x}}
\end{align*}
$$